# Why only 5 icons for "quick status" notifications on lock screen?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia-550

Why is the number of apps for which I can have an icon on the lock screen (showing the number of new messages etc., i.e. the "quick status" notification) limited to 5?

Given the proliferation of messengers and the things you'd probably want to have there in any case (like the number of missed calls, text messages, new mails etc.) this is simply not enough and I cannot see why there is this arbitrary limit.

Is there any way around it?

Comment: For apps that have a live tile, having these pinned to your start screen can work as a work around...

Answer (score 2):

There currently is no way around the 5-icon-limit.

AFAIK there is no official statement from Microsoft to why that is. But from a usability point of view 5 (+/-2) items are the maximum number of items a normal person can process "on a single glance".